# EventSource is not triggering on addEvent listenning

Tags: javascript, html, server-sent-events

I don't know how to catch the event from EventSource with javascript. I am doing it like that, but "running" never appears in the console.

```
        var es = new EventSource(myUrl);

        es.addEventListener("time", function(e){
         console.log("running")
        }, false);

        es.onopen = function(){
          console.log('open')
        },
        es.onerror = function(e){
          console.log('error')
        },
```

It log on 'open' and I see in the network section in the browser console that it is connected and updating every 5 s, when i curl to the server i am getting response every 5 s:

```
:ok

event: time
data: {"data":"tick","ttl":"60","published_at":"2014-08-22T08:26:17.624Z","id":"53ff6e065067544829091287"}

event: time
data: {"data":"tick","ttl":"60","published_at":"2014-08-22T08:26:22.630Z","id":"53ff6e065067544829091287"}
```

how can I catch this event in JS?

Comment: Just read through the docs -- just an off chance:   Did you check the end-of-line character you are sending?

Comment: there is the inforamtion like that: "Note: If a line doesn't contain a colon, the entire line is treated as the field name, with an empty value string." does it mean i need a colon after event: time ?

Comment: I'd double check this: `The stream must then be parsed by reading everything line by line, with a U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN U+000A LINE FEED (CRLF) character pair, a single U+000A LINE FEED (LF) character not preceded by a U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN (CR) character, and a single U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN (CR) character not followed by a U+000A LINE FEED (LF) character being the ways in which a line can end.`

Comment: @jeremyJStarcher thanks for help! but i think i don't understand what you just posted. CARRIAGE RETURN U+000A is a new line, right, nothing about colon. So what exactly i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

First the bad news: it looks correct.

The space after the colon is allowed by the standard. But there is never a good reason to use it, and it just wastes a byte of bandwidth, so the first thing I would try is to remove the space. If that does indeed fix it you might be dealing with a browser bug (let us know).

The second thing I'd try is to use the default event. So:

- Server-side: stop sending your `event:time` line.
- Client-side: change to use the 'message' event handler.

Like this:

```
es.addEventListener("message", function(e){
  console.log("running");
  }, false);
```

If that does not fix it, start looking at exactly what whitespace you are sending. If it does fix it, there is something weird going on with the event header.

However, you could also side-step this issue. I personally never use the `event:` line, and instead always put the event type in the JSON data. Your `"data":"tick"` might already be doing that, but if not it can be as straightforward as sending data like this:

```
data:{"event":"time","data":"tick","ttl":"60","published_at":"2014-08-22T08:26:17.624Z","id":"53ff6e065067544829091287"}

data:{"event":"time","data":"tick","ttl":"60","published_at":"2014-08-22T08:26:22.630Z","id":"53ff6e065067544829091287"}

data:{"event":"somethingElse","this":"and","that":[9,8,7]}
```

Comment: P.S. Forgot the blatant plug: I cover the `event:` line in chapter 8 of my book, Data Push Apps With HTML5 SSE. The primary reason I don't use it is the book shows how to support older browsers, and using an event line makes everything more complicated. A secondary reason is that for typical use-cases of SSE it offers no advantages.